# Login/Startup Scripts Not working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login-script, startup-scripts, logoff-scripts

My test network setup is as follows.

A Windows 2008 R2 Server acting as a DC (AD, DNS, DHCP) it is on its own vlan (10.20.99.0/24).
I then Have two XP test computers each on there own vlan (10.20.98.0/24 and 10.20.97.0/24).

For the vlans with the test computers I have the IP helper-address set to 10.20.99.255, they are able to obtain an IP correctly and logon to the domain.

At the moment I am testing all my GPO by using the default domain policy (I know this isn't the best idea but once I have them working there i will move them before going live).

Normal stuff like disabling start menu items and desktop setting are working fine but no matter how hard I try I cant get any login/startup script to work, I have tested the script on all the computers (it copy's the winexit screensaver from a share on the server to the computers sys32 directory) and it works fine when i manually run it but it doesn't work when I have it set as a login/startup script.

Am I doing something total wrong or have I just missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the permissions on the share holding those scripts isn't right. A startup script is executed as SYSTEM on the local machine. That means that that computer account, or the Domain Computers group needs read access to the share.

Comment: Recreated the share from scratch got it working thanks